# How to sort the messy content in a text file into a single column

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, command

For example, I have a file `word.txt` with the content of

```
monkey horse monkey        elephant
horse monkey


horse
```

How do I use a one line shell script command such as

```
./sortContent word.txt
```

with an output as follows?

```
monkey 
horse
monkey
elephant
horse 
monkey 
horse
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep with its `-o` option to print every match on a separate line; the regex looks for any contiguous groups of printable characters:

```
$ grep -o '[[:graph:]]*' word.txt
monkey
horse
monkey
elephant
horse
monkey
horse
```

Comment: This is probably faster and is definitely easier to pipe into sort than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, this will split a file into individual white-space separated tokens:

```
for w in `cat words.txt`; do echo $w;  done;
```

To sort, just pipe the result through `sort`.